# Need to get the multi-digit integer Entry value after the last digit key is pressed

Tags: python, tkinter

I am relatively new to tkinter, and very new to coding with classes.  My GUI will have a step that asks user to enter in an integer with any number of digits to an Entry(). After the last digit keypress (no keypress in 2000 ms) another function will activate that uses the integer entered. It seems very simple but I cannot seem to get this right. I haven't figured out the .after() part, for now I am just using a binding on the ENTER key. Details on the problems, then the code below. I feel like I am struggling way too much on something that can't be that difficult.  Please help.

(Some?) Details:

- I am getting a bunch of errors leading up to entry input, regarding    'val' not being defined, despite it being defined.
- Pressing ENTER does not result in any return value (I added a print command to the mouse clicks just to see if 'val' was being assigned)
- Losing sleep from trying to apply after() function

Code (I tried to strip down to essentials best I could, my problem is near the bottom):

'''

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox
kk = 1

class App(tk.Tk):
    
    WIDTH = 1000
    HEIGHT = 520
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.geometry(f"{App.WIDTH}x{App.HEIGHT}")
        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.on_closing)  # call .on_closing() when app gets closed
                
        self.fr0 = tk.Frame(master=self, background = 'grey')
        self.fr0.pack(fill = 'both', expand = True,  padx = 20, pady = 20)
        
        # configure grid layout (2x1)
        self.fr0.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        self.fr0.columnconfigure(1, weight = 1)
        self.fr0.rowconfigure((1,2,3), weight = 1)
        
        # Title    
        
        self.lab_bcwt = tk.Label(self.fr0, text = 'Title', font=("Roboto Medium", 40), justify = 'center')
        self.lab_bcwt.grid(row = 0,rowspan = 2,  columnspan = 2)
        
        # ===============================
        
        self.fr1 = tk.Frame(self.fr0)#, fg_color=("black","grey"))
        self.fr1.grid(row=2, rowspan = 2, columnspan = 2, sticky = 'nsew', padx = 10, pady = 10)
        self.fr1.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        self.fr1.columnconfigure(1, weight = 1)
        self.fr1.rowconfigure((0,1,2,3,4,5), weight = 1)
        
        # ===============================
        
        self.fr2 = tk.Frame(self.fr1)
        self.fr2.grid(row=0, columnspan = 2, sticky = 'new', padx = 10, pady = 10)
        self.fr2.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        self.fr2.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)

        # ===============================

        self.lab1 = tk.Label(self.fr2, text = 'This text appears first\n (click to continue)', font=("Ariel", -22), justify = 'center')
        self.lab1.grid( row = 0, columnspan = 2, padx = 10, pady = 5)
        
        
        self.bind("<Button-1>",self.click)
        
        
        
    def on_closing(self, event=0):
        self.destroy()    
    
    def exmp_gps(self):

        self.lab1.destroy()
        self.lab2 = tk.Label(self.fr2, text = 'Then this text appears second,\n telling you to input an integer', font=('Ariel', -22))
        self.lab2.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = 'new', padx = 10, pady = 10)
        self.lab3 = tk.Label(self.fr1, text = 'Any Integer', borderwidth = 2, font = ('Ariel', 12))
        self.lab3.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = 'ne', padx = 10)
        
        
        self.entry1 = tk.Entry(self.fr1, text = 'any integer', justify = 'center')
        self.entry1.grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = 'nw',padx = 10)
        self.entry1.configure(font = ('Arial Rounded MT Bold', 13))
                
        def key_pressed(event):
            global val
            val = int(self.entry1.get())
            # print(val)
        
        self.entry1.bind("<KeyRelease>", key_pressed)
        
        # Ideally 
        
        
        self.entry1.bind("<Return>", print(['Function using', val+1]))
    
    def click(self,event):
        global kk
        if kk == 1:
            self.exmp_gps()
        if kk > 1:
            print(['Function using', val+1])
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

'''

Comment: Your `bind` method is trying to use `val` before you have defined it, look at your indentation.  You have `val` defined in your nested function, you need it defined before you try to use the `bind` method  in your example.

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: `bind` needs function's name without `()` - but you use `print()` and it runs it at once, not when you  press `Enter`. You would need to use `lambda:print(...)` . And you could use normla `self.val` instead of `global val`. You coula also define `key_pressed()` as normal function in class instead of nested function.

Comment: instead of `kk = 1` you could use `self.visible = False` and later `if not self.visible: self.visible = True ; self.exmp_gps(); else: print('Function using', self.val)`

Comment: [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/): inside `()` use `=` without spaces. ie. `text='Title'` instead of `text = 'Title'`

Comment: I greatly appreciate everyone helping here.  Especially furas, your help was essential, and your code worked better than my ideal!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is few problems in code.

`bind` needs function's name without `()` but you use `print()` so it first runs `print()` (which returns `None`) and later it binds `None` to `<Return>`. You could bind `lambda event:print(...)` to run `print()` when you press Enter.

Code could be more readable if you would use normal `self.val` instead of `global val` and if normal function in class `def key_pressed(self, event):` instead of nested function.

Everytime when you click button then it runs `clik()` and it runs `self.exmp_gps()` and it creates new `Entry`. You should increase `kk` in `click()` to run `self.exmp_gps()` only once. And to make it more readable you could use ie. `self.visible = False` and later set `self.visible = True`

You think it can be simple to activate function 2000ms after last keypress - but it is not. It would have to use `after()` and remeber its ID and time when it was created (to delete it if next key will be pressed before `2000ms`, and use new `after()`).

Using `Enter` is much, much simpler.

---

Full code with changes.

I added `after()` but I didn't test it - maybe in some situations it may run function many times.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox

class App(tk.Tk):
    
    WIDTH = 1000
    HEIGHT = 520
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.geometry(f"{App.WIDTH}x{App.HEIGHT}")
        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.on_closing)  # call .on_closing() when app gets closed
                
        self.fr0 = tk.Frame(master=self, background='grey')
        self.fr0.pack(fill='both', expand=True, padx=20, pady=20)
        
        # configure grid layout (2x1)
        self.fr0.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.fr0.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.fr0.rowconfigure((1, 2, 3), weight=1)
        
        # Title    
        
        self.lab_bcwt = tk.Label(self.fr0, text='Title', font=("Roboto Medium", 40), justify='center')
        self.lab_bcwt.grid(row=0, rowspan=2, columnspan=2)
        
        # ===============================
        
        self.fr1 = tk.Frame(self.fr0)#, fg_color=("black","grey"))
        self.fr1.grid(row=2, rowspan=2, columnspan=2, sticky='nsew', padx=10, pady=10)
        self.fr1.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.fr1.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.fr1.rowconfigure((0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), weight=1)
        
        # ===============================
        
        self.fr2 = tk.Frame(self.fr1)
        self.fr2.grid(row=0, columnspan=2, sticky='new', padx=10, pady=10)
        self.fr2.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.fr2.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        # ===============================

        self.lab1 = tk.Label(self.fr2, text='This text appears first\n (click to continue)', font=("Ariel", -22), justify='center')
        self.lab1.grid(row=0, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=5)
        
        self.bind("<Button-1>", self.click)
        
        self.val = 0
        self.visible = False
        self.after_id = None
        
    def on_closing(self, event=0):
        self.destroy()    

    def key_pressed(self, event):
        self.val = int(self.entry1.get())
        print('[key_pressed]', self.val)
        
        if self.after_id:
            print('[key_pressed] cancel after:', self.after_id)
            self.after_cancel(self.after_id)
            self.after_id = None
            
        self.after_id = self.after(2000, self.process_data)
        print('[key_pressed] create after:', self.after_id)
        
    def process_data(self):
        print('[process_data]')
        
    def exmp_gps(self):

        self.lab1.destroy()
        
        self.lab2 = tk.Label(self.fr2, text='Then this text appears second,\n telling you to input an integer', font=('Ariel', -22))
        self.lab2.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='new', padx=10, pady=10)
        
        self.lab3 = tk.Label(self.fr1, text='Any Integer', borderwidth=2, font=('Ariel', 12))
        self.lab3.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='ne', padx=10)
        
        self.entry1 = tk.Entry(self.fr1, text='any integer', justify='center')
        self.entry1.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='nw', padx=10)
        self.entry1.configure(font=('Arial Rounded MT Bold', 13))
        
        self.entry1.bind("<KeyRelease>", self.key_pressed)
        self.entry1.bind("<Return>", lambda event:print('[Return] Function using', self.val))
    
    def click(self, event):
        if not self.visible:
            self.visible = True
            self.exmp_gps()
        else:
            print('[click] Function using', self.val)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: "bind needs function's name without () but you use print() so it first runs print() (which returns None) and later it binds None to <Return>. You could bind lambda event:print(...) to run print() when you press Enter."
-You're absolutely right, I don't know how I forgot lambda. Also I didn't know you could use event in lambda, so thanks for that too.

Comment: "Code could be more readable if you would use normal self.val instead of global val and if normal function in class def key_pressed(self, event): instead of nested function."
-Noted. Doing it this way is indeed much better. I see now I should have used self in a number of places.

Comment: "Everytime when you click button then it runs clik() and it runs self.exmp_gps() and it creates new Entry. You should increase kk in click() to run self.exmp_gps() only once. And to make it more readable you could use ie. self.visible = False and later set self.visible = True"
-There is a reason I used kk. This is one piece of a guide that the user clicks through, and this step actually happens around the 4th click. I just thought it prudent to strip down to essentials.  But thanks anyway, I'm gonna use the self.visible method elsewhere.

Comment: "You think it can be simple to activate function 2000ms after last keypress - but it is not. It would have to use after() and remeber its ID and time when it was created (to delete it if next key will be pressed before 2000ms, and use new after()). is much, much simpler. "
-Honestly I was just trying for pausing before registering the integer. You are right that canceling if key is pressed is much more complicated. But what you wrote worked! I very much appreciate all your help!